# Java: ZipOutputStream algorithm

Tags: java, stream, compression, zip, output

I was thinking of using the ZipOutputStream class in Java for one of my applications.

Unfortunately, all the documentation which I have found for this does not say what algorithm the class uses by default. Does it use gZip? Bzip2? LZMA or XZ? Or the 'deflate' algorithm.

Comment: You mean `class ZipOutputStream extends DeflaterOutputStream`? (Note also that gzip *is* Deflate.)

Comment: The package description sounds pretty straightforward.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed to know. So is it true that DeflaterOutputStream just compresses, instead of using entries and headers, like ZipOutputStream does?